# In IntelliJ how to configure JPA facet if you have pure java config and no persistence.xml file in Spring Bot Project

Tags: intellij-idea, facet

In IntelliJ how to configure JPA facet if you have pure java config and no persistence.xml file in Spring Bot Project

Comment: for a **Spring Boot** project

Comment: I am using IntelliJ **version 14**

Comment: For IntelliJ Ultimate **version 15**, it has auto-detected the facets correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded to version 15.

For IntelliJ Ultimate version 15, it has auto-detected the facets correctly.
This autoconfigures the JPA Facet, and it also generates the ER Diagram.

Kudos IntelliJ 15